# Can detect wifi, but not my wifi

Tags: wireless, detect

Ubuntu(i am using 13.04) can detect many wifi networks, but not mine. I don't know why or how to fix it. I have many other devices that are connected to my wifi(called Elvis). I have connected to several networks using Ubuntu before. Can someone please help me connect to Elvis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to me too before after I changed my WiFi's name. I reset my modem and convert all settings back to factory settings. Then I was able to see my WiFi. Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a connection manually on yourself.

Just open **Edit Connections** from the connection menu and **Add** a new wi-fi connection. Fill in **SSID** and select WPA2 security and enter the password. I hope this will work.